# How do I get data from the YouTube api on a page loaded by ajax?

Tags: jquery, ajax, facebook, youtube-api

I'm using the following code to simply get me a view count from a specific YouTube video and place it in a div with the ID: ytviews:

```
var video_id='gRcGLk6izZ0';
$.getJSON('http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/'+video_id+'?v=2&alt=jsonc',function(data){
document.getElementById('ytviews').innerHTML = (data.data.viewCount);
});
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/KESwY/1/)

Here's my problem:

The div I am placing the view count in resides on a page loaded via AJAX. So when I visit the page when loaded with AJAX the view count doesn't show.

Here's the AJAX code:

```
$(function () {
    var b = "",
        a = $("#main-content");
    $("#page-wrap");
    $(document).delegate(".dyn a", "click", function () {
        window.location.hash = $(this).attr("href");
        return !1
    });
    $(window).bind("hashchange", function () {
        String.prototype.toTitleCase = function (b) {
            var a = this;
            1 !== b && (a = a.toLowerCase());
            return a.replace(/\b[a-z]/g, function (a) {
                return a.toUpperCase()
            })
        };
        b = window.location.hash.substring(1);
        document.title = window.location.hash.replace("#", "").replace(/[_]/g, " ").replace(".html", "").replace("and", "+").toTitleCase();
        b && a.find("#guts").fadeOut(200, function () {
            a.hide().load(b + " #guts", function () {
                a.fadeIn(200);
                $(".dyn a").removeClass("current");
                $(".dyn a[href=" + b + "]").addClass("current")
            })
        })
    });
    $(window).trigger("hashchange")
});
```

I had this same issue with Facebook likes which I solved using the following code to allow the FBML to be re-parsed after AJAX content has been inserted into the DOM:

```
$(document).ajaxComplete(function(){
    try{
        FB.XFBML.parse(); 
    }catch(ex){}
});
```

I have tried putting my view count code within this ajaxComplete solution, which kinda worked except it makes the Facebook Links go crazy and flash in the page.

Could anyone help me understand how I can make both successfully load after the AJAX content has been loaded.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you show the AJAX code that loads the page? You should be able to put the `$.getJSON` above into the success callback of that code.

Comment: @mccannf I've updated my question with the AJAX code. Could you tell me where the success callback would come?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `load` callback, you can add your $.getJSON:

```
    ...
    b && a.find("#guts").fadeOut(200, function () {
        a.hide().load(b + " #guts", function () {
            a.fadeIn(200);
            $(".dyn a").removeClass("current");
            $(".dyn a[href=" + b + "]").addClass("current");
            $.getJSON('http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/'+video_id+'?v=2&alt=jsonc',function(data) {
                  $('#ytviews').html(data.data.viewCount);
            });
        })
    })
    ...
```

Comment: Yes! That works. And it makes complete sense now I see it. Thanks @mccannf